# Why doesn't the MongoDB's index work like it set up?

Tags: database, mongodb

I am having a problem with indexing in MongoDB. I have created an index like this:

```
user_id_1_platform_1_type_1_alive_1
```

And when I query, the 'slow' log of database returns this

> 2019-11-17T19:35:57.182+0700 I COMMAND  [conn1428] command
>   dev_store.users command: getMore { getMore: 27512324353,
>   collection: "devices", batchSize: 899, $db: "dev_store" }
>   originatingCommand: { find: "devices", filter: { user_id: { $gt: 72819
>   }, platform: { $gt: 4 }, alive: true }, sort: { user_id: 1 },
>   projection: { user_id: 1 }, limit: 1000, $db: "dev_store" }
>   planSummary: IXSCAN { user_id: 1, platform: 1, type: 1, alive: 1 }
>   cursorid:27512324353 keysExamined:909 docsExamined:899
>   cursorExhausted:1 numYields:134 nreturned:899 reslen:32346 locks:{
>   Global: { acquireCount: { r: 270 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r:
>   135 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 135 } } } protocol:op_msg
>   3252ms

As it's displayed in the log, I query for user_id  with condition by fields: user_id, platform and alive. But the database still does it very slowly.

So, what is the problem with my current compound index or did I do something wrong in this step? Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I've just tried to write down some executionStats by query like this

> db.users.explain('executionStats').find({ user_id: { $gt: 2283572 }, platform: { $gt: 4 }, active: true })

And the result is

```
 {
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "dev_store.users",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "alive": {
            "$eq": true
          }
        },
        {
          "platform": {
            "$gt": 4
          }
        },
        {
          "user_id": {
            "$gt": 2283572
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "LIMIT",
      "limitAmount": 1000,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "keyPattern": {
            "user_id": 1,
            "platform": 1,
            "alive": 1
          },
          "indexName": "user_id_1_platform_1_alive_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "multiKeyPaths": {
            "user_id": [],
            "platform": [],
            "alive": []
          },
          "isUnique": false,
          "isSparse": false,
          "isPartial": false,
          "indexVersion": 2,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "user_id": [
              "(2283572.0, inf.0]"
            ],
            "platform": [
              "(4.0, inf.0]"
            ],
            "alive": [
              "[true, true]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": [
      {
        "stage": "LIMIT",
        "limitAmount": 1000,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "filter": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "alive": {
                  "$eq": true
                }
              },
              {
                "user_id": {
                  "$gt": 2283572
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern": {
              "platform": 1
            },
            "indexName": "platform_1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
              "platform": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
              "platform": [
                "(4.0, inf.0]"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 1000,
    "executionTimeMillis": 21,
    "totalKeysExamined": 1014,
    "totalDocsExamined": 1000,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "LIMIT",
      "nReturned": 1000,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 20,
      "works": 1015,
      "advanced": 1000,
      "needTime": 14,
      "needYield": 0,
      "saveState": 9,
      "restoreState": 9,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "invalidates": 0,
      "limitAmount": 1000,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "nReturned": 1000,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 20,
        "works": 1014,
        "advanced": 1000,
        "needTime": 14,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 9,
        "restoreState": 9,
        "isEOF": 0,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "docsExamined": 1000,
        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "nReturned": 1000,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
          "works": 1014,
          "advanced": 1000,
          "needTime": 14,
          "needYield": 0,
          "saveState": 9,
          "restoreState": 9,
          "isEOF": 0,
          "invalidates": 0,
          "keyPattern": {
            "user_id": 1,
            "platform": 1,
            "alive": 1
          },
          "indexName": "user_id_1_platform_1_alive_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "multiKeyPaths": {
            "user_id": [],
            "platform": [],
            "alive": []
          },
          "isUnique": false,
          "isSparse": false,
          "isPartial": false,
          "indexVersion": 2,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "user_id": [
              "(2283572.0, inf.0]"
            ],
            "platform": [
              "(4.0, inf.0]"
            ],
            "alive": [
              "[true, true]"
            ]
          },
          "keysExamined": 1014,
          "seeks": 15,
          "dupsTested": 0,
          "dupsDropped": 0,
          "seenInvalidated": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host":"Apps",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "3.6.9"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Comment: Please post the output of `db.collection.explain('executionStats').find(...)` of that query. The log line is useful, but doesn't tell us how the server planned to execute that query.

Comment: @kevinadi I've just updated the result as you described, please check it. Many thanks!

Comment: It says the winning plan is an index scan. So the index is being used. If it has to return 2983088 records, there is no way this can be very fast, index or not.

Comment: @Thilo my mistake, I updated this, I just want to query for 1000 items

Comment: @Thilo the problem this when I use the console to query, it works fine, but when I use Java driver, the slow issues comes.

Comment: Do you also get 1000 items in the console? Or just the default 20?

Comment: I used both and them worked, but I dont know why did I use the Java driver, it was so slow